# In CI, I want to login 3 different usr Role's acount present in 3 different db table's of my db namd as m_admin,, m_faculty ,m_supervisior

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

In code igniter I want to login 3 different user's of different roles from one login page whose username and passwords are presented in different database table using "if elseif & else" in my controller i think that if form validation is true than it will go to if and when if is not correct it will go to elseif and if it doesn't work then it will go to third one i.e m_faculty and if it also don work then it will show alert that u have inserted wrong id and password by this if else I'm able to redirect to go to "faculty/m_dashboard" only that is my faculty dashboard other redirections are not working any when know why its not working or any better way to do this ..........?????

```
public function Auth()
{
    $rules = array(
        array('field' => 'username', 'label' => 'Username', 'rules' => 'required'),
        array('field' => 'password', 'label' => 'Password', 'rules' => 'required'),
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $Msg = array('Msg' => validation_errors(), 'Type' => 'danger');
        $this->session->set_flashdata($Msg);
        redirect(base_url() . 'Admin/');
    }

    # faculty dashboard dashboard


    elseif ($this->form_validation->run() == true) 
    {
        $username = $this->lib->validate($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->lib->validate($this->input->post('password'));

        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($username);
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($password);          
        $count = $this->lib_model->Counter('m_faculty', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 0));

        if ($count == 1) {
            $Sessions = array(
                'EmpCode' => $username,
                'EmpName' => 'Administration',
                'ELogin' => true);
            $this->session->set_userdata($Sessions);

            $Msg = array('Msg' => ' Have a Nice Day ', 'Type' => 'success');
            $this->session->set_flashdata($Msg);
            redirect(base_url() . 'Faculty/f_dashboard');


        }
    }

    #supervisior dashboard

    elseif ($this->form_validation->run() == true) 
    {    

        $username = $this->lib->validate($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->lib->validate($this->input->post('password'));

        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($username);
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($password);          
        $count = $this->lib_model->Counter('m_supervisior', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 0));            

        if ($count == 1) {
            $Sessions = array(
                'EmpCode' => $username,
                'EmpName' => 'Administration',
                'ELogin' => true);
            $this->session->set_userdata($Sessions);

            $Msg = array('Msg' => ' Have a Nice Day ', 'Type' => 'success');
            $this->session->set_flashdata($Msg);
            redirect(base_url() . 'Supervisior/supervisior_dashboard');
        }
   }

    #admin dashboard


    elseif ($this->form_validation->run() == true)  
    {
        $username = $this->lib->validate($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->lib->validate($this->input->post('password'));

        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($username);
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($password);          
        $count = $this->lib_model->Counter('m_admin', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 0));          

        if ($count == 1) {
            $Sessions = array(
                'EmpCode' => $username,
                'EmpName' => 'Administration',
                'ELogin' => true);
            $this->session->set_userdata($Sessions);

            $Msg = array('Msg' => ' Have a Nice Day ', 'Type' => 'success');
            $this->session->set_flashdata($Msg);
            redirect(base_url() . 'Admin/dashboard');
        } 
    }

#error msg

    else {
        $Msg = array('Msg' => 'Username and Password Invalid', 'Type' => 'danger');
        $this->session->set_flashdata($Msg);
        redirect(base_url() . 'Admin/');
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe it would help if you format (code indention) your code, so it is easier readable for you and for us?

Comment: You should never clean a submitted password.  Child Haley Joel Osment whispers: "I see code duplication".

Answer (score 0):

your code won't work because after the first validation check it will always get stuck in your first else clause.

I'm not sure what exactly you are doing here - but a possible approach would be

```
public function Auth()
{

    try
    {
        $rules = array(
            array('field' => 'username', 'label' => 'Username', 'rules' => 'required'),
            array('field' => 'password', 'label' => 'Password', 'rules' => 'required'),
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) throw new Exception(validation_errors());

        $username = $this->lib->validate($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->lib->validate($this->input->post('password'));

        $arrAuthenticationTypes = [
            [
                'table' => 'm_faculty',
                'view' => 'Faculty/f_dashboard'
            ],
            [
                'table' => 'm_supervisior',
                'view' => 'Supervisior/supervisior_dashboard'
            ],
            [
                'table' => 'm_admin',
                'view' => 'Admin/dashboard'
            ],
        ];

        foreach($arrAuthenticationTypes AS $arrAuthenticationType)
        {
            $count = $this->lib_model->Counter($arrAuthenticationType['table'], array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 0));
            if ($count == 1)
            {
                $Sessions = array(
                    'EmpCode' => $username,
                    'EmpName' => 'Administration',
                    'ELogin' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($Sessions);
                $Msg = array('Msg' => ' Have a Nice Day ', 'Type' => 'success');
                $this->session->set_flashdata($Msg);
                redirect(base_url() . $arrAuthenticationType['view']);
            }
        }

        throw new Exception('Username and Password Invalid');
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        $arrMessage = [
            'Msg' => $e->getMessage(),
            'Type' => 'danger'
        ];
        $this->session->set_flashdata($Msg);
        redirect(base_url() . 'Admin/');
    }
}
```